# Fantasy series where a group of good warriors are watched by a magic being who created stars in the sky

Tags: story-identification, tv

In this series there was a creeper in a forest (expansive, intelligent, dangerous) and one day a group "good warriors" find the "centre" of this creeper and kill its heart. There was someone like a witch and wizard or another mystic person (god?) and they, using magic (crystal ball or mirror?), watch "a group of good warriors". One day the "witch" created some stars in the sky and a "wizard" removed them saying that "there was tightly on the sky".

I watched it between 2000-2003 but it was in central Europe, it could be created earlier.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You scare-quoted "good warriors;" were they not actually good?  I also don't understand your last quote; are you certain the wording is correct?  Was this live-action or animated?

Comment: Live-action. I`m not English language native ;) Good warriors were good. Gods or witch and wizard see "adventures" these warriors. They have seen them in the mirror or crystal ball or something like this. I remember event that witch (?) created a star on the sky and wizard (?) removed this star because "there was too much stars".

Comment: Did you watch the series in English or in another language?

Comment: Polish lector, English original I think.